# VHDL comparing have no output

Tags: compare, output, vhdl, modelsim

I have a problem. This is my main code:

```
--Comparer
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity comp is
    generic(N : natural := 1);
    port    (bitVec1, bitVec2: in bit_Vector(N-1 downto 0);
         outVec: out bit_Vector(N-1 downto 0);
         same: out bit);
end comp;

architecture struktur of comp is
begin
    p1: process(bitVec1, bitVec2)
    begin
    if bitVec1 = bitVec2 then
        same <= '1';
    else
        same <= '0';
    end if;

    if bitVec1 >= bitVec2 then
        outVec <= bitVec1;
    else
        outVec <= bitVec2;
    end if;
    end process;
end architecture struktur;
```

And this is my benchtest:

```
--Comparer Test
entity test is
end test;

architecture bench of test is

component comparer
    generic(N : natural := 1);
    port    (bitVec1, bitVec2: in bit_vector(N-1 downto 0);
         outVec: out bit_Vector(N-1 downto 0);
             same: out bit);
end component;

constant MAX : natural := 3;
signal bitVec1, bitVec2, outVec: bit_vector(MAX downto 0);
signal same : bit;

begin
    UUT:comparer    generic map(MAX)
            port map(bitVec1, bitVec2, outVec, same);
    bitVec1 <= "1000", "1001" after 100 ns;
    bitVec2 <= "1000";
end bench;
```

My problem is, that my program has no output. My output "same" is everytime 0 when i test and "outVec" everytime 0000. Why is that so, i have no clue?

Comment: same is '0' and output is "0000" because UUT comparer is unbound. You have several mistakes. The first is that your entity name comp doesn't match the component declaration or component instantiation in test. That's a typo (or two typos). Next MAX is declared as 3 and used in the declarations for bitVec1, bitVec2, outVec in test while conveyed to N as 3 and used as N-1 in comp. You have a mismatch in length which would result in a runtime error. Declare MAX as 4, in the declarations (MAX - 1 down 0). That's two more typos.

Comment: Works fine now. Thank you.:)

Comment: Remember to read all "Warning" and "Error" information from the tool you use for simulation or implementation. This kind of problem is often notified with a very understandable message. In modelsim : `# ** Warning: (vsim-3473) Component instance "UUT : comparer" is not bound.`